# Codeigniter rewriting URLs replace question marks with slashes

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I'm developing a web using PHP Codigniter,
I want to make my URLs look nicer,
For example I want this URL:

```
http://localhost/mlotfy/freelancing/quiz/view_quiz?id=25
```

To look like this:

```
http://localhost/mlotfy/freelancing/quiz/25
```

I've tried this Rewriting rule in .htaccess file but didn't work out(404 page not found)

```
RewriteRule quiz/([0-9]+)    quiz/view_quiz?id=([0-9]+)
```

Comment: Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: You can use CI routing instead of .htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```html
RewriteRule ^quiz/([0-9]+)/?$ quiz/view_quiz?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```